# scripting help for a google sheet that pulls data from google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

so I've been building an inventory spreadsheet to keep track of keys for various locks under all employees with my organization.  I basically copied this code from a YouTube video and tweaked a few things to make it work for my needs.   I need a little help to just clean up my final sheet for a full view of all data.

so what this script basically does it pulls data from multiple spreadsheets in a folder, then posts data to a new sheet combining all data from said folder.  I then make a sheet for each department, which then goes into a new folder.  Finally I run a tweaked version of the same script in a new sheet to pull the combined data to a master sheet with all data from every department.

here is the code of my master sheet

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date)
  .setFontSize(12);
};

function CombineDataToMaster() {
  // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx // Folder ID track crew example
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 
var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();

  var file;
  var fileType;
  var ssID;
  var combinedData = [];
  var data;
 
  
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId()
      data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      data = data.map(function(r){ return r.concat([file.getName()]);   });
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
     
    } //if ends here
  } //while ends here
  
 
  
  
  
  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  ws.getRange("A2:E").clearContent();
  ws.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);
  
} 
 
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:D200").getValues();   
  return data;
  
}
```

so the last function at the bottom is the only part im having a problem with.  I manually entered
`var data = ws.getRange("A2:D200").getValues();` A2:D200  there is no sheet that goes beyond 200 entries in that column.  if I leave that range from A2:D instead it throws 1000 entries into my final sheet with empty cells.  I want this script to only pull data to the end of the sheet.  if that makes any sense.   the data this script is pulling from is different from each sheet, some sheets only have 6 entries of data, while others have 150+ entries.

when i run my script each departments data is entered but then it also adds in anywhere from 10-180 extra entries with empty cells.  makes the sheet harder to read since the data is scattered between blank rows that only display the file name.

`var data = ws.getRange("A2:D200").getValues();`
so i just need this to getrange from A2:D(end of data in said sheet) how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the data range from the sheets at the function of `getDataFromSpreadsheet`.

In this case, I think that `getLastRow()` can be used. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:D" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues(); // <--- Modified
  return data;
}
```

- In this modified script, when `ssID` is changed and the data range is changed, the value of `ws.getLastRow()` is for each sheet.

#### Reference:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: @Mark Thompson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.